# Is it possible customize SFSafariViewController like edit "Share" button?

Tags: ios, swift, sfsafariviewcontroller, sfsafariviewcontrollerdelegate

Is it possible customize SFSafariViewController like:
- change "Share" button
- or add new button on same toolbar where "Share" and "Compass" buttons are
[image: SFSafariViewController]

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. However, you can change some specific configuration of that controller. Namely:

- through `SFSafariViewControllerConfiguration`, you have `barCollapsingEnabled` and `entersReaderIfAvailable`.
- Data for `activityItemsForURL` and `excludedActivityTypesForURL`.
- `preferredBarTintColor` and `dismissButtonStyle`, etc...

Apple says:

> Important
>
> In accordance with App Store Review Guidelines, this view controller
>   must be used to visibly present information to users; the controller
>   may not be hidden or obscured by other views or layers. Additionally,
>   an app may not use SFSafariViewController to track users without their
>   knowledge and consent.

Lastly, indeed, you may use `WKWebView` instead for further customisation of your screen.

> If your app lets users view websites from anywhere on the Internet,
>   use the SFSafariViewController class. If your app customizes,
>   interacts with, or controls the display of web content, use the
>   WKWebView class.

Read doc: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/sfsafariviewcontroller